# R format of date trouble

Tags: r

I'm confused as to why this `as.Date("201410", "%Y%m")` is not converted to a date... That is, I expect that the format article of the function `as.Date` in the example would take the `"201410"` and convert it to date.

Any help?

Comment: what date would you expect that to return with?

Comment: it returns with `NA` @hrbrmstr

Comment: i know what it does return. What would you think it _should_ return.

Comment: a date - it's being treated as a character prior, and I think the `as.Date` should return a date.

Comment: A date has a year, month and day at a minimum. a "date" is not a nebulous concept. It's actually an integer at the lowest level. there is no concept of (for example) 2015-03-00. So, I still can't fathom what you think a day and month should be converted to.

Comment: ahhh - I suppose I am looking for a year/month - that makes sense. Thank you for the clarification - long day...

Comment: Think of it this way, is this `2014-10-01` or `2014-01-10`?  `as.Date` does not know without more information...

Comment: There is a `yearmon` class in pkg:zoo.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns "%Y%m" IS more information...

Comment: In any case note that `?as.Date` specifies: If the date string does not specify the date completely, the returned answer may be system-specific. The most common behaviour is to assume that a missing year, month or day is the current one. If it specifies a date incorrectly, reliable implementations will give an error and the date is reported as NA. Unfortunately some common implementations (such as glibc) are unreliable and guess at the intended meaning.

Comment: how about `as.Date(paste0("201410","01"),format="%Y%m%d")`?  May be you can add a date to conform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to make the assumption that these dates are on average occurring at the middle of a month then this would be a dodgy way of using the Date class:

```
 as.Date(paste0("201410", "01"), "%Y%m%d")
#[1] "2014-10-01"
```

This is how to create a yearmon object:

```
>  require(zoo)

> as.yearmon("201410","%Y%m")
[1] "Oct 2014"
```